# Action button in WooCommerce admin orders list that send the customer invoice

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

in Wordpress admin dashboard, when you open woocommerce order page, you will see list of the orders and the columns are (Order, Date, Status, Billing, Shipping, Total, **Actions**)

I would like to add a new button for Action list and then add this action to send the Email Invoice to the customers which orders are still on-hold.

[image]

I have created the column and the button as below, but I have trouble with calling the action button to send the invoice to the customers for each order.

please advice.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button', 100, 2 );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button( $actions, $order ) {

    if ( $order->has_status( array( 'on-hold' ) ) ) {

        // The key slug defined for your action button
        $action_slug = 'invoice';
        $status = $_GET['status'];
        $order_id = method_exists($the_order, 'get_id') ? $the_order->get_id() : $the_order->id;
        // Set the action button
        $actions[$action_slug] = array(
            'url'       => admin_url('post.php?post=' . $post_id . '&action=edit&message=11'),
            'name'      => __( 'Invoice', 'woocommerce' ),
            'action'    => $action_slug,
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}

add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css' );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css() {
    $action_slug = "invoice"; // The key slug defined for your action button
    echo '<style>.wc-action-button-'.$action_slug.'::after { font-family: woocommerce !important; content: "\e029" !important; }</style>';
}
```

Comment: Some feed back on my answer below will be really appreciated please.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** *(added missing `'`)*.

The following will add  on admin orders list actions column an action button for orders with an "on hold" status. The button send the customer invoice notification via admin Ajax.

The complete code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_admin_order_custom_actions_button', 100, 2 );
function add_admin_order_custom_actions_button( $actions, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status( array( 'on-hold' ) ) ) {
        // The key slug defined for your action button
        $action_slug = 'email_invoice';

        // Set the action button
        $actions[$action_slug] = array(
            'url'    => wp_nonce_url(
                admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=send_invoice_email&order_id=' . $order->get_id() ),
                'send-invoice-email'
            ),
            'name'   => __( 'Send Invoice', 'woocommerce' ),
            'action' => $action_slug,
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_invoice_email', 'trigger_customer_email_invoice' );
function trigger_customer_email_invoice() {
    if ( current_user_can('edit_shop_orders') && check_admin_referer('send-invoice-email') &&
    isset($_GET['order_id']) && get_post_type( absint( wp_unslash($_GET['order_id']) ) ) === 'shop_order' ) {
        $order_id = absint( wp_unslash($_GET['order_id']) );

        WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Invoice']->trigger($order_id); // Send email
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_invoice_sent', 'OK' ); // For testing purpose (to be removed)
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css' );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css() {
    $action_slug = "email_invoice"; // The key slug defined for your action button
    echo '<style>.wc-action-button-'.$action_slug.'::after { font-family: woocommerce !important; content: "\e02d" !important; }</style>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: it doesn't work. after press on the button, it goes to this page and showing a blank page.
example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=send_invoice_email&order_id=25845&_wpnonce=16155d51b2

Comment: Yep, same for me even with the missing `'` fixed.

Comment: oh wait, it actually works and sent the email, but it is redirected to a blank page only. anyway to redirect it back to the order page?

Comment: Yes, that would be nice. Leaving an blank page after is not very useful. It should go "back" to the Orders page.

Comment: @HaroldAldersen I have removed the redirection… So the email is just sent, each time the related action icon is pressed.

Comment: you can use ```\wp_safe_redirect``` and then ```exit``` after you have done all the logical parts inside your ajax callback function.